# Tie Wordpress Blog into single website login session so login required when blog selected in menu

Tags: php, wordpress, session, authentication

I have found multiple postings with similar phrases but all too specific to their issue and not addressing this...

Most of the website requires a login session. I have built a custom plugin for WordPress to handle my CMS needs, etc. I have included a blog in the website. However, my issue is... How do I require login when "blog" is selected on the menu. AND I do NOT want to show WordPress anything. I want the blog to look like the rest of the site.

Basically I want to "nest" the blog in my website with one required login session. I have the menu item "blog" set as a category so as to pull the WordPress pre-built functionality. So this is the only item I am not able to php a login session as there really isn't a page to do so.

I have read several things. But finding them a bit confusing. Many say to change the wp-config.php but I am not comfortable with changing core files within WordPress. What am I missing or misunderstanding?

**UPDATE:**
Would changing the menu selection to a "page" instead of "category" and insert php file within that page with a redirect using `header('Location:mysite.com/blog_files` (of course after session verified) to redirect where WordPress has stored my blog? Is this a viable work-a-round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your wordpress as API point. Wordpress comes with REST API. So what you can do is get all posts after certain action. Then parse them in html.

There are 2 things to keep on mind. 
1st is that everything on wordpress is post.
2nd is that to change certain parts of how api works you add filters to functions.php.

Hope I was helpful.

Comment: thank you. Can you point me to resource to accomplish this? I appreciate your time and assistance! Also can you check my update, above, and tell me your thoughts?

Comment: You don't need redirect. Inside that php file you're doing authetification you can make call to  wordpress-blog.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts. This will fetch all posts from your wordpress blog in json format. Then you can parse json to show visitors.

Comment: I like your thoughts. Do you have a basic example code? or point me to resource. I apologize I am a newbie

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. Make ajax request to url of your wordpress + /wp-json/wp/v2/posts for example https://stuntcoders.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts and then just parse json and add it to variable. You can do with php foreach json and add row from it to html .

Comment: No worries. I appreciate your time and help! I will look into this. It will take me a bit as I am new and unfamiliar. But I think this is going to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**
I have successfully "nested" my blog into my website so that login session is required. Changing the menu selection to a "page" instead of "category" and insert php file within that page with a redirect using `header('Location:mysite.com/blog_files` (of course after session verified) to redirect where WordPress has stored my blog files. This was quick and easy. However, it still requires WP login to participate in the blog.  :(

Comment: It still requires a WordPress login to respond to the blog posts. So back to Nikola suggestion.